# Speed difference between assign function value and not assign to a variable

Tags: c++, performance, math, assembly, trigonometry

So this is really a mystery for me. I am Measuring time of my own sine function and comparing it to the standard sin(). There is a strange behavior though. When I use the functions just standalone like:

```
sin(something);
```

I get an average time like (measuring 1000000 calls in 10 rounds) **3.1276 ms** for the standard sine function and **51.5589 ms** for my implementation.
But when I use something like this:

```
float result = sin(something);
```

I get suddenly **76.5621 ms** for standard sin() and **49.3675 ms** for my one. I understand that it takes some time to assign the value to a variable but why doesn't it add time to my sine too? It's more or less the same while the standard one increases rapidly.

**EDIT:**
My code for measuring:

```
ofstream file("result.txt",ios::trunc);
file << "Measured " << repeat << " rounds with " << callNum << " calls in each \n";
for (int i=0;i<repeat;i++)
{
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    //call the function here dattebayo!
    for (int o=0; o<callNum;o++)
    {
      double g = sin((double)o);
    }

    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto difTime = end-start;
    double timeD = chrono::duration <double,milli> (difTime).count();
    file << i << ": " << timeD << " ms\n";
    sum += timeD;
}
```

Comment: I would say that compiler succeeds to optimize in one case by seeing that `sin(x)` is no op.

Comment: Hmm so you think that the compiler has some list of such functions? Cause it clearly doesn't cover user functions.

Comment: There is probably an issue with the way you are measuring. Can you post the profiling code?

Comment: I'd suggest generating assembler output files. They'll probably show that the compiler optimized out standard sin because it has no side effects but kept your sin function.

Comment: Maybe the compiler can not prove that your implementation has no side-effects. BTW, is it in a separate compilation unit (that is, in a separate .cpp that is compiled separate from the main program)?

Comment: First of all, do you measure in **Release** mode?

Comment: Even a more interesting question, what is your compiler and what are compile options?

Comment: @Thomas Good point, I was in debug haha now it shows only 0 ms :D

Comment: @Petr Using gcc  and no special options, just a default CodeBlocks settings. And the function is in the same cpp file.

Comment: @WernerHenze yes I might try that

Comment: You should add all sin() return values to g and print that out after the loop and time measuring. Then the compiler cannot optimize out the calls to sin() (and thus the whole loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any modern compiler, the compiler will know functions such as `sin`, `cos`, `printf("%s\n", str)` and many more, and either translate to simpler form [constant if the value is constant, `printf("%s\n", str);` becomes `puts(str);`] or completely remove [if known that the function itself does not have "side-effects", in other words, it JUST calculates the returned value, and has no effect on the system in other ways].

This often happens even for standard function even when the compiler is in low or even no optimisation modes.

You need to make sure that the result of your function is REALLY used for it to be called in optimised mode. Add the returned values together in the loop...

Comment: Wow that you, this solves it! Alright, another example when computers are way too clever :D
I also needed to print that sum value in the end to make it work.